# input range значения над полосой

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

подскажите, как можно сделать, чтобы выбирались только цифры из datalist ? и можно ли их поставить над инпутом в линию, чтобы каждая цифра соответствовала значению инпута

```
<input type="range"  id="fader" name="timeshool" list="volsettings">
                            <datalist id="volsettings">
                                <option>30</option>
                                <option>45</option>
                                <option>60</option>
                                <option>90</option>
                                <option>120</option>
                            </datalist>
```

Comment: так никто и не подсказал\

Comment: 1. Да можно, Air ниже даже код представил. 2. Да, тоже можно, но это уже велосипедить нужно)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Рассказываю, в чем суть: вначале мы создаем массив из значений `<option>`. Далее навешиваем на ползунок событие при его перемещении. При каждом его движении получаем его значение и создаем новый массив из (!!!) модулей разности этого значения с каждым значением из массива `<option>` (`values`). Это нужно, чтобы понять к какому значению `<option>` мы сейчас ближе всего (к какому начали движение). Чтобы узнать точно куда мы должны прийти вычисляем минимальное значение массива этих разностей и получаем (!) всего лишь минимальную разность (расстояние до ближайшей точки остановки). Но индекс под которым это значение лежит в массиве разностей и есть индекс значения массива `values` к которому мы движемся. Соответственно это значение мы и применяем сразу же после начала движения. Все.

Выполните код, чтобы попробовать его в деле. Раскомментируйте логи, чтобы понять, что происходит.

```js
let values = [];

$("datalist > option").each((index, item) => {
 values.push($(item).html());
});

let min = (obj) => {
    var a = obj[0];
    for (var i = 1; i < obj.length; i++) {
        if (obj[i] < a) {
            a = obj[i];
        }
    }
    return a;
}

$("input[type='range']").on("input", (e) => {
 let element = $(e.currentTarget);
  let value = element.val();
  
  let differenceArr = [];
  values.forEach((item, index) => {
   differenceArr.push(Math.abs(item - value));
  });
  //console.log(differenceArr);
  let minDifferense = min(differenceArr);
  //console.log(minDifferense);
  let newValue = values[differenceArr.indexOf(minDifferense)];
  //console.log(newValue);
  element.val(newValue);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
  <input type="range" min="0" max="120" value="30"  id="fader" name="timeshool" list="volsettings">
  <datalist id="volsettings">
    <option>0</option>
    <option>30</option>
    <option>45</option>
    <option>60</option>
    <option>90</option>
    <option>120</option>
  </datalist>
</body>
```